# Can't update software, file in use

Tags: windows-7

I have a problem on my PC. It happens quite often, that I want to update some kind of software (e.g. games with some kind of launcher who updates the game or even a normal update via MSI. Yesterday it was "Anti-Malware Bytes" and before it was the updater of Aion.) and the update fails, because the updater can't overwrite/delete some exe files. Sometimes it works after a few tries.
I am not able to delete the files manually, too, same error, but I couldn't find any process that is still running. Uninstalling throws the same error. Booting in safe mode and deleting the file there worked.

I've already checked the PC with a live-cd virus scanner, a normal virus scanner and anti-malware bytes. No results.

The user is of course an administrator.

Any ideas except reinstalling windows?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that I would do to further investigate would be to download the [Handle.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) utility from MS. run that and determine what process is routinely locking up the files.

Comment: Good start, I will try it at home.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to get [Process Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Explorer), which will let you track down who has a file open.

Comment: Care to explain how this is done?

Comment: You click file and enter the filename.